# Instagram login in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, instagram

I am implementing instagram in my application.I am following the code from "https://github.com/crino/instagram-ios-sdk"

This code is working fine and instagram call is made in the app delegate.
"self.instagram = [[Instagram alloc] initWithClientId:APP_ID delegate:nil]"

But I want to use this in the view controller not in the app delegate.
When I try to do that it is not calling the "-(void)authorize:(NSArray *)scopes" method and so Instagram is not loading.

Please suggest me some way out for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. My code:

```
    self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

     self.webView.delegate = self;

 NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:kAuthenticationEndpoint, kClientId, kRedirectUrl]]];

 [self.webView loadRequest:request];

 [self.view addSubview:self.webView];
```

Where: `kAuthenticationEndpoint=@"https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&response_type=token%22;`

Answer (score -2):

My code:

```
    UIWebView *webViewInstagram = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    webViewInstagram.delegate = self;
    [webViewInstagram setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:webViewInstagram]; 

    NSString *urlRedirect = @"REDIRECT_URL";
    NSString *clientId = @"CLIENT_ID";
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&response_type=token",clientId, urlRedirect];

    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:30];

   [webViewInstagram loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: its confusing to use redirect_uri =  redirectURL.. its fairly different